Fastest way to divide by a symmetric positive matrix
Say $P_{yx}$ is a general $(n_y,n_x)$ matrix.
Say $P_y$ is symmetric, positive definite, of size $(n_y,n_y)$.
I want to compute $GT=P_y\backslash P_{yx}$ (matrix left division, or perhaps more explicitly : $GT=P_y^{-1}P_{yx}$). I see two ways to do that and am trying to figure out which would typically require the least amount of computations.
In both cases, start by computing $S_y$, the upper triangular Cholesky square root of $P_y$, such that $S_y^TS_y=P_y$.
Then

Option 1 : compute $U=S_y^{-1}$, inverse of $S_y$ (which is relatively easy since $S_y$ is upper triangular) ; compute $V=UU^T$ (we have $V=P_y^{-1}$) ; and finally compute the standard matrix multiplication $VP_{yx}$.

Option 2 : simply apply matrix left division twice, computing $GT=S_y\backslash (S_y^T\backslash P_{yx})$ (exploiting the triangular property of both denominators).


Obviously the answer will depend on $n_x$ and $n_y$.
If $n_x>>n_y$, there will come a point where option 1 will obviously be more favorable as Option 1 is mostly dealing with $(n_y,n_y)$ objects and $n_x$ only appears at the last step.
If $n_x<<n_y$, it is reasonable to conclude the opposite will be true, as it should be more favorable to work with objects of size $(n_y,n_x)$ rather than $(n_y,n_y)$.
Aside from these asymptotic behaviors, is there a more refined expectation on where to switch from one method to the other, depending on $n_x$ and $n_y$ relative values ? For example, what if $n_x=n_y$ ? What if $n_x=3n_y$ ? $5$ ? etc.

Notation $P_y\backslash P_{yx}$ has become classical in linear algebra software (Matlab etc...) but not in "mathematical linear algebra", especialy for non-square matrices. You should recall their exact definition involving $(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$

I have added the info at the start that $P_y\backslash P_{yx}$ is equivalent to $P_y^{-1}P_{yx}$.
